# Porting code from Android to Windows Phone

Tags: c#, android, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am searching for the similar C# code for android code for below part.
`atttemptMappingD` is an object.

```
Enumeration<?> keysE = (Enumeration<?>) ((JSONObject) atttemptMappingD)
                    .keys();
            while (keysE.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) keysE.nextElement();
                String value = ((JSONObject) atttemptMappingD).getString(key);
}
```

can anyone please suggest me how I will achieve this in C#.
for `JSONObject` I am using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, hope this will help for someone.

```
var keysE = ((JObject)atttemptMappingD).ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();

foreach (var item in keysE)
{
     string key = (string)item.Key.ToString();
     string value = ((JObject)atttemptMappingD)[key].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to JSON is an API for working with JSON objects. It has been designed with LINQ in mind to enable to quick querying and creation of JSON objects. LINQ to JSON sits under the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq namespace.` You can have Full Refrence from here([LINQ to JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm)) how it can be done as per your Requirements.

Comment: thanks for reply, but actually I need the similar code for C#. Can you please guide.

Comment: In that Doc code snippets are given... you can easily go through them, just try that out, you would not need any guide for sure

Comment: and what will be substitute for this

`Enumeration<?> keysE = (Enumeration<?>) ((JSONObject) atttemptMappingD).keys();
            while (keysE.hasMoreElements()) `

Comment: for `TYPE` you can use object as Datatype for Enumeration.